# Python interpreter's relationship with scripts

Tags: python, scripting, execfile

In my current directory, I have a `foo1.py` script and a directory named other with a `foo2.py` script inside.

Now:

I launch the interpreter, and using `execfile` I can launch both scripts. The thing is, when I edit and save `foo1.py`, I don't have to restart the interpreter, I just `execfile` again and it runs with my modifications, but the same doesn't happen with `foo2.py`. For the edits I made to `foo2.py` to take effect I have to quit and relaunch the interpreter, since even after saving it `execfile('foo2.py')` will run the same script as before...

This is annoying, as I wanted to constantly be editing and launching multiple scripts in sucession, who often depend on each other...

How can I make it soo that the interpreter sees my edits to `foo2.py`, without having to restart it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for the reload() function and the restrictions mentioned there; depending on your python version it is located in different modules, for 2.x it is predefined.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a "recent" Python, you could try the following syntax compatible with Python 2.6, 2.7 and 3.x

```
with open('foo2.py') as file:
    exec(compile(file.read(), 'foo2.py', 'exec'))
```